# Search while selection enabled in macro VS2015

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2015, macros

On VAX/VMS (or OpenVMS Alpha and its other names) there was an editor called TPU.  In TPU you could enable selection of text independently of holding a key down.  You pressed SELECT and then any cursor movement you made selected text between the editing point and the new cursor location.

You could also record macros.  So you could use this text selection feature to create macros like:

- find "abc"
- select
- find "xyz"
- cut
- stop recording

So this macro would find any line with "abc" in it and then cut all text between "abc" and "xyz".  Massive time saver.

Making sense?  How can I do that in VS2015?  I can't find a macro extension that provides the selection behaviour I need to do this.

Cheers,

.pd.

**EDIT**

It occurred to me this could be done with a regex but it seems like a pretty big ask.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Property, Model.SelectListProperty, htmlAttributes: new { @class="whatever" })
// the regex would replace this with
@Html.MyDropDownListFor(m => m.Property, Model.SelectListProperty, Model.Property, htmlAttributes: new { @class="whatever"})
```

So I would be looking for a regex to 
- find @Html.DropDownList
- replace the token 1 of that line split by ',' with token 1 of token 0 split by '.' and prefixed with "Model."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Model.Property` comes from `m => m.Property`.

Search for

```
@Html\.DropDownListFor\(((\w+)\s*=>\s*\2\.(\w+)),\s*(Model\.\w+)(,(?:[^(){}]|\{[^{}]*\})*)?\)
```

Replace with

```
@Html.MyDropDownListFor($1, $4, Model.$3$5)
```

Demo: http://regexr.com/3f3io

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  It definitely works with this specific format.  I guess the exercise for me now is to pull this apart to understand what it's doing so I can get it to work with other formats.  

E.g. I don't get a match with @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].award, (SelectList) Model[i].award_SelectList, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control col-med"}) 

But like I said that's an exercise for me.  Thanks again.  (thumbsup)